# Text marker not visible on svg path element

Tags: html, svg, marker

I am trying to display text markers at the start and/or end of a line, or any path element in an SVG element on an HTML page in a web browser (tried Chrome, Firefox and IE). This is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<svg width="500" height="500" viewport="0 0 500 500">
    <defs>
        <marker id="markerCircle" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="5" refY="5">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" style="fill: black; stroke: black;"/>
        </marker>
        <marker id="markerTriangle" markerWidth="15" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="5"     orient="auto">
            <polygon points="0,0 0,10 15,5" style="fill: black;"/>
        </marker>
        <marker id="markerText" markerWidth="15" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="0">
            <text x="0" y="0">hello</text>
        </marker>
        <text id="textTemplate" x="0" y="0">hello</text>
    </defs>
    <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="10"
          style="stroke: black;
                 marker-start: url('#markerText');
                 marker-end: url('#markerTriangle');"/>
    <text x="50" y="100">hello</text>
    <use xlink:href="#textTemplate" x="50" y="200"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

The text displays just fine when included directly as an element in the SVG and also when it is 'defined' and 'used'. The 'markerCircle' and 'markerTriangle' path shapes work fine on the line element. The text however does not show when used as a marker. If I understand the W3 recommendation correctly, text markers should work (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerElement). What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin for text is (by default) the bottom left corner. Text at 0,0 is mostly displayed at negative y co-ordinates. Markers clip (by default) to the box (0, 0, markerWidth, markerHeight) so your text is basically not inside the marker visible area.

You could move the text (increase the y) or set overflow on the marker to visible.

Comment: Great! Both solutions work perfectly. Thank you for your fast reply.